# Terraform Azure VM SSH Key

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am new at Terraform and would like some help. I have successfully created a VM and can manually SSH into it with no problem. The issue is I am working with a team on a project and they can't do any changes to the Tf files without making Terraform delete all the resources and recreating them. I think this is because they have a different SSH Key from mines.

```
admin_ssh_key {
   username = "azureroot"
   public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")}
```

Because the contents of my ssh key is different from my teammates, it will destroy the VM and recreate it using the key from the person who did the terraform apply. Is there any way to get around this? This has caused many issues because we have had multiple vms destroyed because of the keys were different.

Comment: There are a few ways around this. If both you are using the same user, you could combine both the public keys together. Not a good idea, but works. 
Another one would be via `cloud-init` wherein you could add the user and keys but Azure `waagent` needs to be told and you may have problems while snapshotting the instance because of stale user data. 

I don't understand why both the teams are creating the same resource..

Comment: The teams are not creating same resources. An example is if I am the first person to do the terraform apply, my key would be associated with the VM. But then later on, my teammate needs to make a modification to an Inbound/Outbound rule, and does a terraform plan, it will delete the vm and spin a new one up, even though we made no changes to it. When I look at the output it’s because terraform detected a different Key (because my key is different from my teams)

Comment: okay. In that case, club both the keys together. `public_key - (Required) The Public Key which should be used for authentication, which needs to be at least 2048-bit and in ssh-rsa format. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.`
Refer this:: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/linux_virtual_machine.html

Comment: Any updates for the question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes your answer below helped! Thanks everyone for chiming in.

Comment: If it works for you please accept it as the answer to help other communities who are looking for it, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the configuration of the VM. It seems like you use the resource `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine` and set the SSH key as:

```
admin_username      = "azureroot"
admin_ssh_key {
   username = "azureroot"
   public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
}
```

For the public key, you use the function `file()` to load the public key from your current machine with the path `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. So when you are in a different machine, maybe your teammate's, then the public key should be different from yours. And it makes the problem.

Here I have two suggestions for you. One is that use the static public key like this:

```
admin_username      = "azureroot"
admin_ssh_key {
   username = "azureroot"
   public_key = "xxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Then no matter where you execute the Terraform code, the public key will not cause the problem. And you can change the things as you want, for example, the NSG rules.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help someone who have the same issue with me.

You can generate new private key and public key using terraform configuration language. Here is the following example:

```
resource "tls_private_key" "example_ssh" {
    algorithm = "RSA"
    rsa_bits = 4096
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "myterraformvm" {
    computer_name = "myvm"
    admin_username = "azureuser"
    disable_password_authentication = true

    admin_ssh_key {
        username = "azureuser"
        public_key = tls_private_key.example_ssh.public_key_openssh #The magic here
    }

    tags = {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Terraform is not a good use case for your problem. A system user for bootstrap or updates should have the key locked away. For traceability I would lock the private key only for use during a [break-glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_access_control#Break-Glass_Access_Control_Models) scenario.

If you want everyone to use a different key but the same user, I would suggest looking at a configuration management tool such as puppet, chef, ansible, salt, the list goes on.  Otherwise you should share the key.

https://serverfault.com/questions/471753/what-are-best-practices-for-managing-ssh-keys-in-a-team/471799

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement this would be to use a cloud-init file and either add multiple users with their own public keys or populate the authorized_keys file of your admin user. You could then use a tool like Ansible to update authorized_keys later.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/cloud-init

Ansible module -
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/authorized_key_module.html

Ansible "Ad Hoc" commands -
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_adhoc.html

Answer (score 1):

While for ongoing access you should have separate users/accounts, during provisioning you will have to specify a single user that will serve as the VM administrator.
To overcome the different secret hashes between you and your teammates, you can generate a new Key that will be used for provisioning, share the private key in the team and store the public key in the Azure KeyVault.
Then when building the VM as Terraform to pull the public key from KeyVault and use it.

```
# Get existing Key Vault
data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                = "kv-dev-mgmt"
  resource_group_name = "rg-master"
}
# Get existing Key
data "azurerm_key_vault_key" "ssh_key" {
  name         = "dev-mgmt-ssh-key"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}
```

```
# Create a VM
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                            = .....
  resource_group_name             = .....
  location                        = .....
  size                            = .....
  admin_username                  = "adminuser"
  admin_ssh_key {
    username = "adminuser"
    public_key = data.azurerm_key_vault_key.ssh_key.public_key_openssh
  }
  disable_password_authentication = true
```

Refer to https://isbyr.com/how-to-use-an-ssh-key-stored-in-azure-key-vault-while-building-azure-linux-vms-using-terraform/ for step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add everyone's public key to the same file which is used to create the root ssh key. this is the pragmatic approach but should not be promoted as a standard.
for best practices you should be adding each user as an individual so that their user and the public key is created by our provisioning and they then login as their own user and escalate privilege as required

Comment: this won't work see https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/652

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this issue, is to use the [`azurerm_ssh_public_key`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/ssh_public_key) data source in Terraform to access an SSH Public Key created outside of Terraform. Here's how the codes would look like:

```
data "azurerm_ssh_public_key" "SshPublicKey" {
  name                = "ssh_key_name"
  resource_group_name = "rg_name"
}
```

and inside the `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine` resource:

```
admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = data.azurerm_ssh_public_key.SshPublicKey.public_key
  }
```

If you and your teammates refer to the same SSH Key within the above data block, your problem should be resolved.

Please note that using the [`tls_private_key`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs/resources/private_key)  resource to create an SSH Key is not recommended, since the private key generated by this resource will be stored unencrypted in your Terraform state file. Instead, generate a private key file outside of Terraform and use the above data source to access it in your Terraform configuration files.